# Checking updates for rss feed every minute using etags

Tags: python-3.x, rss, etag, last-modified, feedparser

This is the code I am using for checking RSS feed updates. I am storing the last modified and etag of the feed in variables . whenever there is an update i am updating these 2 variables and rechecking every minute. Is this logic correct ? Kindly help .

```
last_etag=None
last_modified=None
d=feedparser.parse(url)
    last_etag=d.etag if "etag" in d else None
    last_modified = d.modified if "modified" in d else None
while(True)
   d2=feedparser.parse(url,etag=last_etag,modified=last_modified)
   if d2.status==304:
     continue
   elif d2.status==200:
     #process the entries
     #check database for updated entries using d2.entries
     #download those entries and update database
     #update etag and last_modified values
     last_etag=d2.etag if "etag" in d2 else None
     last_modified = d2.modified if "modified" in d2 else None
   time.sleep(60)
```